# What's the meaning of "upstairs people"?

Tags: meaning

I'm learning English by watching this TV show on Netflix called That 90s Show.

In one of the scenes adults are sitting around a table playing cards and one of them say:
"Enjoying yourselves, kids? You're upstairs people now". And other one responds:
"I knew it would happen. Just not this soon".

So, what's the meaning of been an upstairs person?

Comment: There is no enough context to tell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a reference to the original show (That 70's Show). The kids used to hang out in  Formans' basement all the time while the grown ups were upstairs. I have not actually seen the spin-off but I'm guessing it's about the kids growing up and becoming the "upstairs people" now; The opposite of what they used to be in the original show for all the 8 seasons.

Comment: I think this must be it. I'm not aware of a general purpose expression about "upstairs people."

Comment: That answer totally makes sense to me. Leia's parents and grandparents were the ones around the table having this conversation and by the end of the episode her grandparents arrange their basement so she can hang with her friends in there during the summer. Thank you!